# What is a usual order relation?

Tags: relations

I've just started learning about relations and now I'm at partial order relations and total order relations; essentially, I'm trying to convey that I'm very much a beginner to this relations stuff.

My textbook includes the following remark:

> The usual order relation on the real line $ \Bbb R $ is a total order relation.

A little later in my textbook is the following exercise (a portion of it, anyways):

> Let $A$={1,2}.
>   List all the partial order relations on A.  (The usual order relation on A is $R$={$\mathsf (1,2) \cup E)$}, where $E$={$(1,1),(2,2)$} is the relation of equality on A.      ...)

The textbook also refers to a usual order relation again, somewhere later, so I would like to know what is meant by the term.  I tried to infer something from the exercise whose excerpt I included, but I still don't understand.  I went to mathworld.com and I didn't find anything there.

Comment: The usual order relation is the ordering you would assume someone was talking about if the issue of different possible orders had never come up. So $2$ is less than $5,$ $e^2$ is less than ${\pi}^{2},$ $-3$ is less than $-\frac{1}{2},$ etc.

Comment: The "usual" ordering is the ordering as you are familiar with it.  For instance $n \gt n-1$ in the whole numbers, and the following rules are satisified:  $a \lt b, c \gt 0 \implies ac \lt bc$, multiplying by a $-1$ flips the inequality, and we also have $a \lt b, c \in \Bbb{R} \implies a + c \lt b + c$.  Prove those, using your intuition about real numbers.

Comment: @Enjoys Math:  How come you didn't put this as an answer?  Anyways...then, based on what you wrote, one might say:   S is a relation on $ \Bbb R $ defined by $x R y$ iff there exists a real number $c$ such that if $a < B$, then $a + c = b + c$; and S is the usual order relation on $ \Bbb R $.

Answer (score 1):

The "usual order relation" is a creation of laziness. It's the order relation that your intuition comes up with first when you have to define an order relation on the space it's attached to.

So for $\Bbb R$, it's the ordering of numbers, for $\{1,2\}$ it's the only "sensible" ordering "up to renaming of the elements" (i.e., $1 < 2$). I hope that clears the air.

Answer (score 1):

The usual ordering on $\Bbb{R}$ can be uniquely defined as the total order $\lt$ on $\Bbb{R}$ that satisfies the following two properties:

(Let $a,b,c \in \Bbb{R}$)

1) $c \gt 0 \iff c$ is positive.

2) $a \lt b,  \ \ 0 \lt c \implies ac \lt bc$

Proof that this defines uniquely $\lt$:  Suppose that $\lt'$ also satisfies these properties and is a total order on $\Bbb{R}$.  Then if $a \lt b$, assume that $b \lt' a$.  Then we have $0 \lt' a-b$, or by (1) that $a-b$ is positive.  Then let $c = a-b \gt' 0$.  This connects us to $\lt$ by (1) since we can also then write $c = a-b \gt 0$.  Now we need one more defining property to complete the proof:

3) $a \lt b \implies a + c \lt b + c$

$\square$.